# Wordpress redirecting https to http without any sense only in front-end

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

few days ago I redirected all https to https using .htaccess file and defined through `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` the https just for /wp-admin/. Now I have deleted that options and restored .htaccess file so I expected that all returned to the normality. Now the /wp-admin/ directory behaviour is normal, in fact if I try to put https://example.com/wp-admin/  the website loads with SSL activated, but if I try to put https://example.com the website will make a redirect to https://example.com without a sense.

Do someone knows what cause this ?

If I try to install a plugin the front-end will result in a infinite loop.
If can be helpful i'm running a multisite

Comment: Check your /wp-admin/options-general.php page and make sure your website has https prefix there (in two fields). If not, then it is normal that it redirects https to http. You need to adjust those settings to make https working.

Comment: @Elvin85 which lines I should see ?

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to examine the requests. Is it actually making a request to the HTTP site or using a cached version?

Comment: In the given page you should see two inputs with the website URL. Are they with http or https?

Comment: @Quentin I get a 301 redirect from https to http but I can't understand why

Comment: If you want to make a test gazzettadegliesports.it